# Conditionally Convert a String to a Dictionary in Python

Tags: python, string, dictionary, conditional-statements

I have some data in a string that looks like this:

```
messagePayload = 'Key1: Value; Key2; Value; Key3: Value 3'
```

What I've been using to make a dictionary out of this data is this:

```
messagePayload = dict(item.split(": ") for item in messagePayload.split("; "))
```

However, sometimes a particular key doesn't have a value. For example:

```
messagePayload = 'Key1: Value; Key2:; Key3: Value;'
```

This, of course, crashes. Is there a way filter out the keys that don't have values from being added to the dictionary?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add a condition to the comprehension:

```
messagePayload = dict(item.split(": ") for item in messagePayload.split("; ")
    if len(item.split(': '))>1
)
```

This version requires you to write out (and evaluate) the `split` twice for each item.  You can do it by writing that expression only once, but it requires you to use two nested comprehensions:

```
messagePayload = dict(split for split in
    (item.split(": ") for item in messagePayload.split("; "))
if len(split)>1)
```

Comment: This would be a lot more readable if you broke each one into two lines, since SO makes you horizontally scroll beyond 80 columns.

Comment: Oh my gosh, It's so simple. It's embarrassing how long I've been trying to find a solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think that given the remnant ';' on value 3 and the double split, you might want to consider just a regular ol' loop:

```
mp2='Key1: Value; Key2:; Key3: Value;'
di={}
for kv in mp2.split("; "):
    spkv=kv.split(": ")
    try:
        di[spkv[0]]=spkv[1].rstrip(';')
    except IndexError:
        pass 

print di  
# {'Key3': 'Value', 'Key1': 'Value'}
```